# Deploying an Angular Application to OpenShift via GitLab

Tags: angular, docker, deployment, gitlab, openshift

My company utilizes **OpenShift** for application deployment. As per guidance from my senior, the recommended approach involves utilizing **GitLab** as an intermediate step. The process entails creating and pushing the container to a GitLab repository, and then using that repository (containing the container) to deploy the application on OpenShift.

I'm seeking assistance from anyone experienced in this process to provide detailed steps. Specifically, I aim to deploy an **Angular** application following this workflow.

*Thank you in advance for your guidance.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Set Up GitLab Repository
Create a GitLab Account: If you don't have one already, sign up for a GitLab account.
Create a New Project: In GitLab, create a new project where you'll store your Angular application code.
Clone the Project Locally: Use Git to clone the newly created GitLab project to your local machine.
Step 2: Angular Application Setup
Create Angular Application: If you haven't already, create your Angular application using Angular CLI:

ng new my-angular-app

```
Develop Your Application: Write your Angular application code within the src directory.
Step 3: Dockerize Your Angular Application
Create Dockerfile: In the root directory of your Angular project, create a Dockerfile with the following content:
# Use official Node.js image as the base image
FROM node:14 AS build
# Set the working directory
```

WORKDIR /app

```
# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
```

COPY package*.json ./

```
# Install dependencies
```

RUN npm install

```
# Copy the application files
```

COPY . .

```
# Build the Angular app
```

RUN npm run build -- --prod

```
# Use nginx as the base image for serving content
FROM nginx:alpine
# Copy built Angular app to nginx
```

COPY --from=build /app/dist/my-angular-app /usr/share/nginx/html

```
# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80
# Command to run nginx
```

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

```
Build Docker Image: Build your Docker image using the Dockerfile:
docker build -t my-angular-app .
Step 4: Push Docker Image to GitLab Registry
Tag Your Docker Image: Tag your Docker image with the GitLab registry URL:
docker tag my-angular-app:latest registry.gitlab.com/your-username/my-angular-app:latest
Login to GitLab Registry: Login to your GitLab registry:
docker login registry.gitlab.com
Push Docker Image: Push your Docker image to the GitLab registry:
```

docker push registry.gitlab.com/your-username/my-angular-app:latest

```
Step 5: Deploy to OpenShift
Login to OpenShift: Login to your OpenShift cluster using the command-line interface (CLI).
Create Deployment Configuration: Create a deployment configuration for your Angular application in OpenShift, specifying the GitLab registry image as the image source.
```

oc create deployment my-angular-app --image=registry.gitlab.com/your-username/my-angular-app:latest

```
Expose Service: Expose your application as a service to make it accessible outside the OpenShift cluster:
```

oc expose deployment my-angular-app --port=80 --type=LoadBalancer

```
Access Your Application: Once deployed, you can access your Angular application using the provided route.
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I've tried it and the container got deployed. The issue now I'm having is I'm getting an error in OpenShift regarding nginx.

nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
2024/03/07 05:32:57 [emerg] 1#1: mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)